# Update Script for TextMeshPro

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui, textmeshpro

I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to get this relatively simple script to work with text mesh pro. This is a photo of what I'm attempting and is working with my old script:

[image]

This could just be a settings issue and not a coding issue. Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CurvedText : Text
{
    public float radius = 0.5f;
    public float wrapAngle = 360.0f;
    public float scaleFactor = 100.0f;

    private float circumference
    {
        get
        {
            if (_radius != radius || _scaleFactor != scaleFactor)
            {
                _circumference = 2.0f * Mathf.PI * radius * scaleFactor;
                _radius = radius;
                _scaleFactor = scaleFactor;
            }

            return _circumference;
        }
    }
    private float _radius = -1;
    private float _scaleFactor = -1;
    private float _circumference = -1;

    protected override void OnValidate()
    {
        base.OnValidate();
        if (radius <= 0.0f)
        {
            radius = 0.001f;
        }
        if (scaleFactor <= 0.0f)
        {
            scaleFactor = 0.001f;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        base.OnPopulateMesh(vh);

        List<UIVertex> stream = new List<UIVertex>();

        vh.GetUIVertexStream(stream);

        for (int i = 0; i < stream.Count; i++)
        {
            UIVertex v = stream[i];

            float percentCircumference = v.position.x / circumference;
            Vector3 offset = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, -percentCircumference * 360.0f) * Vector3.up;
            v.position = offset * radius * scaleFactor + offset * v.position.y;
            v.position += Vector3.down * radius * scaleFactor;

            stream[i] = v;
        }

        vh.AddUIVertexTriangleStream(stream);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (radius <= 0.0f)
        {
            radius = 0.001f;
        }
        if (scaleFactor <= 0.0f)
        {
            scaleFactor = 0.001f;
        }
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(circumference * wrapAngle / 360.0f, rectTransform.sizeDelta.y);

    
    }
}
```

Which gives me a circle a of text and is working exactly as intended. I'd really just like to update to text mesh pro to do some fun stuff with materials and shader graph < when I tried with the legacy text it all just appeared to be blocks or the individual letters didn't have a mesh which led me to seeking this upgrade.

```
public class CurvedText : TextMeshPro
```

When I changed to the above it seemed simple enough, but then no text would show. I realized this was because so font was selected. Then I realized the font size defaulted to -99 for some reason. I experimented changing different settings for over an hour to no avail. I included screenshots of all the possible settings.

[image][image]

If someone could either help me adjust these settings to get the text to show up, or help me reconfigure the script for text mesh pro id really appreciate it. Thanks